# How to get the wallet address of my own LND node?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

I have set up a lighting node using LND time ago, now I would like to send more BTC to it.

How can I get the wallet address of my LND node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lncli h` to view a list of all the available commands.

`lncli newaddress` will give you a new address for the wallet. You must specify the address type: either `p2wkh` (pay to witness key hash), or `np2wkh` (nested pay to witness key hash). For example, `lncli newaddress p2wkh`.

(Running lnd v0.6.0-beta)

Comment: I don't want a new address. I want to know the current one. I checked all the commands, can't find any that simply output the current wallet address.

Comment: Ah, well there is no command to display an already-used address, by design. There is really no need to use an address more than once, in fact doing so is very detrimental to your privacy. You **should** use a new address for every transaction.

Comment: I understand the privacy concern. But still, it would be nice to have that information in case you need to check the transactions in the blockexplorer. But ok, if there is no option then I will give up. I though it was me not able to find the command.

Comment: I can understand why you might want the history of addresses, but your Q specifically said you want to send more BTC to already-used addresses. In any case, `listunspent` or `listchannels` will be give you some clues for past addresses, if you’re willing to dig into the blockchain record a bit by following UTXOs through time. I’d be careful about reusing them for new payments though, lest you make a mistake and send funds to an address that is a LN channel by mistake, for example. It would be **very** difficult to recover those funds if a mistake was made.

Comment: Agree with @chytrik, however if you wanted to view all onchain addresses, you could get this information from `listchaintxns`